# Nesting data in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to familiarize myself with D3 and having a hard time getting data in the right format. I have an array of objects that each have a "date" key within them and I'm trying to use d3.nest to group them by date, but can't even get the example to work (taken from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays). I've watered it down to bare essentials, but the code is taken right from the d3 wiki.

```
var yields = [{yield: 27.00, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1931, site: "University Farm"},
              {yield: 48.87, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1931, site: "Waseca"},
              {yield: 27.43, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1932, site: "Morris"}]

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.year; })
    .entries(yields);
```

According to the wiki, this should organize the data in the following structure:

```
[{key: 1931, values: [
    {yield: 27.00, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1931, site: "University Farm"},
    {yield: 48.87, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1931, site: "Waseca"}]},
 {key: 1932, values: [
    {yield: 27.43, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1932, site: "Morris"}]}
]
```

but when checking using `console.dir(yields)` I get the same flat structure as before using d3.nest. Since I can't even get the example from the documentation working, I have no idea what to try next. Help a noob out?

Answer (score 8):

You want to look at `nest`, not `yields`. `yields` is what you passed in and `nest` is what you get out. `yields` doesn't change.

The d3 wiki could have written things in a more readable way:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.year; })

var nested = nest.entries(yields);
```

Now, `nest` is an object you can reuse for similar data with year keys, and `nested` is the output of one `yields`. The `key` function returns the nest object itself, but `entries` returns new nested data.